# How to reduce Space between textfield and the input text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing this textfield and for some reason the text is having some space below it. Please let me know the solution to this.

This is my code for textfield.

```
Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 40,
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: textEditingController,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14, height: 0, color: Colors.white),
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                  ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(

                      // isDense: true,
                      // errorText: validateQtyTxt.toString(),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      labelText: 'QTY > '
                      // hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      ),
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    (text) => setState(() => _text);
                    print(newValue);
                    int qty;
                    derivativeScanController.buttonClick(newValue, qty);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

This is the image for reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beouv.png)

Comment: You can use the following property inside of the InputDecoration: contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:-5),

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called contentPadding which takes EdgeInsetsGeometry type value with that you can reduce the spacing between textfield and actual text
sample code .

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

if you want to remove all the spacing change the isDense property to true also

```
 isDense: true,
```

all the space will be removed

Comment: Please have a look at the image i recently added. I have tried this solution but nothing works.

Comment: can you explain clearly what's your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contentPadding` in the `decoration` property of the `TextField` to edit its padding.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(...),
  ),
)
```

Which you can fill with whatever values you want. You can use things like `EdgeInsets.zero` or `EdgeInsets.symmetric` too:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html

Comment: Please have a look at the image i recently added. I have tried this solution but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the textStyle from 0 to 1 and adjust the text using padding.

Answer (score 0):

Use same padding for icon and the TextFormField

```
        TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Email Address',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),   
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
            prefixIcon: Padding(
              padding:   EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.email_rounded,
                color: black,
                size: 17,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given `height` : `0`, **remove** it & try.

The height parameter increase/decrese the height of TextField & your content isn't align to center.